# Docker microservices and Nginx on Prod

Tags: docker, nginx

Hi I have a machine (server) and nginx(native) installed on this server.

My domain is **hotels.com(for example)**

And subdomain **api.hotels.com**

this is the conf file for subdomain on machine (native nginx):

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name api.hotels.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000$request_uri;;
    }
}
```

I build my app with microservices architecture, 2 services:
**users-service:3030 , payment-service:3080**

**i want to expose api.hotels.com/users/ AND api.hotels.com/payment**

so i choose to use nginx(docker container) as apiGateway on port:3000 and i want to proxy to specific service, so use this config

```
server {
    listen 3000;

    location /users/ {
        proxy_pass http://users:3030/;
    }

    location /payment/ {
        proxy_pass http://users:3080/;
    }
}
```

- in localhost it work fine for me but in server and with domain something wrong happen.

if i try to get http://api.hotels.com i get nginx from nginx(machine): Good

but if try to get http://api.hotels.com/users it rewrite the url in browser to http://127.0.0.1/users and then break.

*Note: i use docker-compose to up this 2 services and nginx container.

Questions:

1) how to fix this?
2) my flow is ok, or have any other flow for this app?

My purpose flow example:

1) Client http://api.hotels.com/users

2) Server all api.hotels.com ==> http://localhost:3000(api gateway)

3) Nginx Container(on port:3000) ==> proxy to spesific service by name (users in this example)

Comment: You are trying to browse wrong URL. Use http://api.hotels.com:3000/users/ instead. And you have missing server_name in your second server block, where your proxy_pass directives for micro services live. It may cause problems.

Comment: Hi but i dont want to use port on prodution for cuatomer, how i can fiz the configuration for mu purpos

Comment: if you don't want to use different port, you have to put your location blocks (on second server block) to the first server block, before the generic location block (location /). It should work that way.

Comment: Cant understand your answer sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application looks good, the problem is only configuration.
you can try this configuration:

```
server {
    server_name api.hotels.com;
    listen 80;

    location /users/ {
        proxy_pass http://users:3030/;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host
    }

    location /payment/ {
        proxy_pass http://users:3080/;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host
    }
}
```

in this case your nginx container expose ports => **INCOMING_PORT:80**

then in your example it will look like this in docker-compose.yml

```
...
services:
   api-gateway:
     image: nginx:latest
     ports:
       - "3000:80"
...
```

in this way your api gateway is more dynamically. you can change the income port any time and nginx inside container will listen for port 80, and will proxy for spesific service by name.

good luck :)